# Error in creating HDInsight cluster through arm template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to **create HDInsight cluster through arm template.** 
I have uploaded **2 files in blob storage** called **template_customized.json & parameters.json.**
For passing password parameters, I have used **key vault concept.** 
If I manually hardcode the password values the arm template works fine. 
But if I provide the keyvault values I get below error:
I am executing the arm template via **cloud shell present in Azure portal** (executed twice)

```
**PS Azure:\>** New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name FirstDeployment -ResourceGroupName xxxx -TemplateUri https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test/template_customized.json -TemplateParameterUri https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test/parameters.json

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 7:18:39 AM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template parse failed: 'Cannot populate JSON array onto type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Templates.Schema.TemplateInputParameter'. Path 'parameters.resources', line 66, position 18.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name FirstDeployment -ResourceGro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name FirstDeployment -ResourceGro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

**PS Azure:\>** New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name FirstDeployment -ResourceGroupName xxxx -TemplateUri https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test/template_customized.json -TemplateParameterUri https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test/parameter

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 7:19:02 AM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template parse failed: 'Cannot populate JSON array onto type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Templates.Schema.TemplateInputParameter'. Path 'parameters.resources', line 66, position 18.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name FirstDeployment -ResourceGro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name FirstDeployment -ResourceGro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

I have de-sensitized blob storage name, storage name, resource group name, subscription id,keyvault name for safety purpose.

**template_customized.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "0.9.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "clusterName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "hdiclustr",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the HDInsight cluster to create."
            }
        },
        "clusterLoginUserName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "admin",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "These credentials can be used to submit jobs to the cluster and to log into cluster dashboards."
            }
        },
        "clusterLoginPassword": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "metadata": {
                 "description": "Password for the Cluster login."
      }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "eastus2",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location where all azure resources will be deployed."
            }
        },
        "clusterVersion": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "3.6",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "HDInsight cluster version."
            }
        },
        "clusterWorkerNodeCount": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 4,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The number of nodes in the HDInsight cluster."
            }
        },
        "clusterKind": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "HADOOP",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The type of the HDInsight cluster to create."
            }
        },
        "sshUserName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "sshuser",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "These credentials can be used to remotely access the cluster."
            }
        },
        "sshPassword": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "metadata": {
                 "description": "Password for the SSH login."
    }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-03-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('clusterName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxxx"
            ],
            "properties": {

                "clusterVersion": "[parameters('clusterVersion')]",
                "osType": "Linux",
                "tier": "standard",
                "clusterDefinition": {
                    "kind": "[parameters('clusterKind')]",
                    "componentVersion": {
                        "Hadoop": "2.7"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "gateway": {
                            "restAuthCredential.isEnabled": true,
                            "restAuthCredential.username": "[parameters('clusterLoginUserName')]",
                            "restAuthCredential.password": "[parameters('clusterLoginPassword')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "storageaccounts": [
                        {
                            "name": "xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net",
                            "isDefault": true,
                            "container": "hdiclustr-2018-09-26t05-51-17-421z",
                            "key": "[listKeys('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxx', '2015-05-01-preview').key1]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "computeProfile": {
                    "roles": [
                        {
                            "autoScale": null,
                            "name": "headnode",
                            "minInstanceCount": 1,
                            "targetInstanceCount": 2,
                            "hardwareProfile": {
                                "vmSize": "Standard_D12_V2"
                            },
                            "osProfile": {
                                "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                                    "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                                    "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                                }
                            },
                            "virtualNetworkProfile": null,
                            "scriptActions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "autoScale": null,
                            "name": "workernode",
                            "targetInstanceCount": 4,
                            "hardwareProfile": {
                                "vmSize": "Standard_D4_V2"
                            },
                            "osProfile": {
                                "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                                    "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                                    "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                                }
                            },
                            "virtualNetworkProfile": null,
                            "scriptActions": []
                        },
                        {
                            "autoScale": null,
                            "name": "zookeepernode",
                            "minInstanceCount": 1,
                            "targetInstanceCount": 3,
                            "hardwareProfile": {
                                "vmSize": "Small"
                            },
                            "osProfile": {
                                "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                                    "username": "[parameters('sshUserName')]",
                                    "password": "[parameters('sshPassword')]"
                                }
                            },
                            "virtualNetworkProfile": null,
                            "scriptActions": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "location": "eastus2",
            "properties": {
                "accountType": "Standard_LRS"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

**parameters.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "clusterName": {
            "value": "xxxxxx"
        },
        "clusterLoginUserName": {
            "value": "admin"
        },
        "clusterLoginPassword": {
            "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxx------xxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "secretName": "xxxxxxx"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "eastus2"
        },
        "clusterWorkerNodeCount": {
            "value": 4
        },
        "clusterKind": {
            "value": "HADOOP"
        },
        "clusterVersion": {
            "value": "3.6"
        },
        "sshUserName": {
            "value": "sshuser"
        },
        "sshPassword": {
            "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx----xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "secretName": "xxxxxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: In the `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` call you should use `-TemplateUri` instead of `-TemplateFile` and `-TemplateParameterUri` instead of `-TemplateParameterFile`

Comment: New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name xxxxxxx -ResourceGroupName xxxxx -TemplateUri xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -TemplateParameterUri xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 5:25:09 AM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template parse failed: 'Cannot populate JSON array onto type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Templates.Schema.TemplateInputParameter'. Path 'parameters.resources', line 66, position 18.'
Thanks for the comment Greg. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the access permissions for both your blob container and for your Key Vault in Azure to ensure you have the correct access permissions.

Also try to run your ARM scripts locally on your machine, and deploy to Azure Powershell (specifying your local scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template parse failed: '**Cannot populate JSON array onto type** 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Templates.Schema.TemplateInputParameter'. Path 'parameters.resources' -

**Answer:** **JSON was valid. But error in the format of template.**

[Difference in curly braces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7cCg.png)

Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: '**The value for the template parameter 'clusterLoginPassword' at line xx and col xx is not provided** -

**Answer:** In the paramter.json file do not add "value" field for parameter's which refer key vault. " Directly start with reference".